# How to distinguish object types in unity hierarchy?

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can you get what type object is? I'm looking at Panel and Image and they have almost the same view. How would I distinguished that mainMenu is a Panel and blankWindow is an Image, if I didn't know what is what?
Panel:

[image]

Image:

[image]

Comment: FYI, Panel is just an Image with a different sprite. That's why you may wonder where the Panel component is. It simply doesn't exist, it's an Image.

Comment: @yasirkula I unerstand you, I see it, but my question is broader. As I got, you mean that I can check type of any object by its components? And there is no another way like for example to find out the spelled name of type of an object in somewhere in hierarchy?

Comment: Distinguishing between a Panel and an Image can be done via Tag (*CompareTag*), Name (*name*) or a Component that exists on only one of these objects (*GetComponent/TryGetComponent*). The type 'Panel' is reflected only to the object's initial name and once you change that name, you can't tell if its source was UI/Panel, UI/Image or a blank RectTransform that you've manually filled with an Image component.

Comment: @yasirkula isn't it a problem? Pretend that you got a project and you see it the first time, you need check all components to understand what they do, but you even can't check is it a Panel or a Image. Isn't it strange?

Comment: All buttons under GameObject menu (whether it is a Cube, Light or Panel) are just helpers/presets for you to create GameObjects with pre-populated components. You can create all of these presets from scratch by creating an empty GameObject and adding it the desired components. To give a GameObject a special meaning (let's say identifying something as a 'Panel'), you should give it a unique tag, a unique component (you can call it MyPanel or even just Panel) or a unique name. As I said, you can't tell which GameObject menu button created a specific GameObject; and I don't think it's a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disagree with the other answer

**There literally is no difference at all.**

"Panel" is just a built-in template name for an object that also uses an `Image` component and by default uses stretching to the full parent rect size while the option "Image" by default has a fixed rect size. So they only differ in the `Anchors` settings.

That's all. There is no further difference between the options "Panel" and "Image". Both use the exact same components, just different default settings.

=> There is no built-in way whatsoever to differ between them on runtime except your implementation and e.g. going by name or tag etc.

Except you really want to go by the anchor settings which I would not recommend at all.

You could also have a custom dedicated class you put on the panel just to identify it

```
public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Doesn't have to do anything
}
```

so you can check if this component is present using e.g. [`TryGetCompoment`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.TryGetComponent.html)

```
if(someObject.TryGetCompomemt<MainMenu>(out var menu))
{ 
    Debug.Log("It'sa me, Main Menu!");
}
```

or find it using [`GetComponentInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInChildren.html), [`FindObjectOfType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html) etc.